# What is Known about Preprocessing for Stabbing Queries?

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, computational-geometry

In a concrete setting, I have the following problem:

given a fixed set of simple objects (e.g. disks or, convex polygons with few vertices), I need to quickly report the objects that are hit (i.e. intersected) by a randomly generated line. While that problem is tied to the euclidean plane, generalizations can easily be formulated.

> **Questions:**
>
> - what are the time complexities for determining all hit-sets (i.e. sets of objects, that can be intersected by the same line) for non-trivial objects in the 2D setting?
>     If the objects are points in general position, the hit-sets correspond to all pairs of points.
> - which algorithms and datastructures allow efficient preprocessing (i.e. determining all hit-sets)?
> - which algorithms and datastructures allow efficient runtime hit-queries?

Depending on space-dimension, kind of objects and, the number of runtime queries, different algorithms and datastructures may be advisable and thus welcome answers.

My problem is however tied to the Euclidean plane and the objects are either convex polygons defined by a mesh or, their enclosing circles for reasons of speedup and, the cost of runtime queries outweighs that of preprocessing; the size of the datastructure plays however a role.

Comment: *Preprocessing of stabbing*? -- .......brrrr!

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński I am also not happy with the naming; but it at least seems to pin-point the problem or are you not happy with the grammar?.

Comment: The grammar is perfect! (as long as I know). :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three remarks:

(1) If you dualize points to lines and lines to points, then you have a *point-location* query problem, on which there is a large literature.

(2) If instead of lines, you use rays and seek only the 1st intersection, they you have a
*ray-shooting* query problem, on which there is a substantial literature.

(3) But even without converting to another problem, there is directly applicable literature. Here is one paper that achieves approximately $O(n^{0.7})$ query time
(i.e., sublinear) for a line intersecting $n$ disks, using only a linear-size data structure:

> van Kreveld, Marc, Mark Overmars, and Pankaj K. Agarwal. "Intersection queries in sets of disks." BIT Numerical Mathematics 32.2 (1992): 268-279. ([Journal link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01994881).)

---

[image: Abstract]

---

Comment: great! that is exactly what was looking for.